# Access field created by Studio in Qweb

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-14

I have been trying to access a studio field(field created using Odoo Studio) within Qweb to retrive information to put on a template. Here is what I am using

```
                        <span>VAT reg. no.: <span t-field="res_company.partner_id.vat" /></span>
                        <br />
                        <span>EORI: <span t-field="res_company.partner_id.x_studio_eori_1" /></span>
                        <br />
                        <span>Phone: <span t-field="res_company.partner_id.phone" /></span>
                        <br />
                        <span>Email: <span t-field="res_company.partner_id.email" /></span>
```

I can access the VAT, Phone and email fields without an issue but the EORI field is created using Odoo studion and I cannot seem to access it here.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a typo?

Comment: @CZoellner I edited the question to add the field name in Odoo. It may not be a typo.

Comment: Just and idea... but have you tried putting studio into your module dependencies?

Comment: @DanielLagiň Nope, can you explain how to do that or where to do that please? Thanks

Comment: In your error the field which is raising the error is `x_studio.eori` which is not the same like in your code above where it is `x_studio_eori_1`. That's why i said it's a typo.

Comment: @CZoellner I am also unable to fathom how the error get x_studio.eori when I have put x_studio_eori_1